# Syntax error Sharepoint 2013 FQL queries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I have created a FQL Query with the Sharepoint Search Query Tool and i get always the a Error 500 SearchServiceExcetpion. And it looks like that the syntax of the query isn't in the right format.

```
and(path:\"https://myHost/Lists/WKPPR/DispForm.aspx*\")
```

I have also enbale FQL. 
[image]

Comment: 1. Have you created an FQL result source?
2. The other option is to pass the FQL as part of the refinement instead, which is FQL
3. Don't escape the input

Comment: i need a fql result source on server side to enable fql? also for the second option? for the second option I pass the and(path:"https://myHost/Lists/WKPPR/DispForm.aspx*") string in the refinement filters box? thx

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163973(v=office.15).aspx for FQL result source, and see http://www.techmikael.com/2014/12/s15e11-fast-query-language-fql-unwanted.html for some info as well :) For the second option, you do not need FQL enabled result source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a FQL result source. Thanks to Mikael Svenson in the comments above.